# How to add MenuItem's to a MenuBar in Vaadin Declarative UI?

Tags: user-interface, vaadin

The MenuItem components are not added to the MenuBar:

```
<v-menu-bar _id="menu" width="100%" />
   <v-menu-item caption="Option 1"/>
   <v-menu-item caption="Option 2"/>
</v-menu-bar>-->
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this [MenuBarDeclarativeTest](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/server/tests/src/com/vaadin/tests/components/menubar/MenuBarDeclarativeTest.java) which suggests that items should be defined with just "menu".

```
String design = "<vaadin-menu-bar auto-open='' tabindex=5>"
            + "<menu checkable=''>Save</menu>"
            + "<menu description='Open a file'>Open</menu>"
            + "<menu disabled=''>Close</menu>"
            + "<menu icon='http://foo.bar/ico.png'>Help</menu>"
            + "<menu visible='false'>About</menu>"
            + "<menu>Sub<menu>Item</menu></menu>"
            + "<menu more>WTF?!</menu>" + "</vaadin-menu-bar>";
```

The same is suggested by the [MenuBar sources](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin/blob/master/server/src/com/vaadin/ui/MenuBar.java)

```
   public void readDesign(Element design, DesignContext designContext) {
    super.readDesign(design, designContext);
    Iterator i$ = design.children().iterator();

    while(i$.hasNext()) {
        Element itemElement = (Element)i$.next();
        if(itemElement.tagName().equals("menu")) {
            MenuBar.MenuItem menuItem = this.readMenuElement(itemElement);
            if(itemElement.hasAttr("more")) {
                this.setMoreMenuItem(menuItem);
            } else {
                this.menuItems.add(menuItem);
            }
        }
    }

    this.setHtmlContentAllowed(!design.hasAttr("plain-text"));
}
```

However the main menu tag should be **v-menu-bar** instead of *vaadin-menu-bar* or you'll get a `com.vaadin.ui.declarative.DesignException: Unknown tag: vaadin-menu-bar`, at least with version 7.5.6 which I am using for the time being.

Using "v-menu-bar" & "menu" I got a fairly normal result :-)
[image]

Comment: You did it again! :) When using Vaadin Declarative UI you need a deep dive in the source code i guess. However it is not clear for me how to bind the MenuItem instances to a command. Using "_id" does not work

Comment: @rmuller I found myself in similar situations so I did my share of digging. After all this is what SO is about, sharing knowledge and helping other, isn't it? Cheers mate

Comment: @rmuller Sorry, I did not see the edit but I added a comment to your other question :)