# How to bind Command to MenuItem in Vaadin Declarative UI?

Tags: user-interface, vaadin

I have the following Vaadin Declarative UI code snippet (also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32906587) question):

```
<v-horizontal-layout spacing width="100%">
   <v-menu-bar style-name="borderless" :bottom :right>
      <menu icon="font://USER">username
         <menu icon="font://HEART">My Preferences</menu>
         <menu icon="font://LOCK">Change Password</menu>
      </menu>
      ...
   </v-menu-bar>
</v-horizontal-layout>
```

How to bind a `MenuBar.Command` to the `MenuItem`s created by the Declarative UI (i.e. "My Preferences" and "Change Password")?

Comment: He he, this might not be as easy as the others since you need to pass command instances to the menu items. I guess you'll have to access the menu in your component, iterate through its items and add specific commands. Or add a generic command which checks the triggering item, and acts accordingly.

Comment: @Morfic Yes, this is what i have so far. But rather ugly, especially in an i18n application, where text and description are both language dependent. The id of a MenuItem is just an internal set `int`, so also useless for binding.

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't found a nicer method yet since defining `_id` for menu-items injection is not an option for the time being. I usually use a mix, declaring only the menu in the design file, and in the associated component class I add the items and commands.